# Java Distrbuted transaction components

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions

I am learning the distributed transactions from Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/xadistra.htm

I came across this statement, please help me in understanding what it means:

> XA functionality is usually isolated from a client application, being
>   implemented instead in a middle-tier environment, such as an
>   application server.
>
> In many scenarios, the application server and transaction manager will
>   be together on the middle tier, possibly together with some of the
>   application code as well.

What can be the client application and what is middle-tier environment? Is middle-tier environment and application server, both are same? I am thinking the application code lies on client application, is that correct?

I am new to these concepts so I am facing difficulty in understanding them, please help me to clarify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you read the [JTA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7286-jta-1.0.1-spec-oth-JSpec/), which provides good conceptual information about what a distributed transaction is.

> What can be the client application and what is middle-tier environment?

A client application is the code that demarcates the transaction boundaries (where the transaction begins and ends)
This client code can execute from a java standalone or from a server side component like a servlet or ejb.

> Is middle-tier environment and application server, both are same?

Think in the  middle-tier as a concept that represents other components involved in a distributed transaction: the transaction manager, the resource manager, and the application server.

> I am thinking the application code lies on client application, is that correct? yes